# run a simple .c file in terminal window10

Tags: c, gcc, terminal

Hi I am having trouble running a simple main.c (hello world program in terminal)
the compiler work: gcc main.c

things I try so far:
1

```
gcc main.c
main
```

> error: 'main' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

2

```
gcc main.c -o main
./main
```

> error: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

3

```
gcc main.c -o main
main
```

> error: access denied

4

```
gcc main.c -o main
a.exe
```

> error: access denied

5

```
gcc main.c
-o main.c
```

> error: '-o' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

what else should I try thank you!

Comment: What output file(s) are you getting? Check with `dir` to see. Note `-o` is an option to `gcc`, it *must* be on the same command. On its own it is meaningless.

Comment: Surely you must have thought about checking what files are in that directory after compilation?

Comment: Word of advice. At the same time you're learning coding, also learn how to use your programming tools. The shell you're using for instance. Learn basic usage with it, how to copy/delete/move/rename files and navigate and other various stuff.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`gcc -o main.exe main.c`

Comment: it seem o work but I do not get my output! would there be a reason why?

Comment: Simply open terminal in the same folder as the **.exe** file and type `{filename}.exe`. @MaudePoulin-labelle

Answer (score 0):

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html
I think you should write the exec file name first (you are using the syntax for unix)
example:
gcc -o main.exe main.c
then it should compile

Comment: it seem to work but I do not get my output ! could that be cause by something else?

Comment: @MaudePoulin-labelle so are you using:  gcc -o main.exe main.c   and then   main.exe   in the same directory?